# mesh network of multiple raspberry pi with python

Tags: networking, wifi, python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth

I am currently working with alerting devices, specifically using raspberry pi 3b+, where it classifies a sound and the classified sound is sent to every alerting device present at home. I am looking for a way to make them connect like a mesh network so that it can send the classified sound as a string to the other device. The system is not connected to the internet and also to routers. We have two technologies to use, Bluetooth and Wi-Fi. Here are my questions:

1. What could I use to make a mesh network for these devices?
2. I searched batman-adv for wifi and Bluez for Bluetooth but I don't know if that will work? Can I use these? If not, what can I use?
3. Is it possible to code the communication of these devices in python? How?
4. What modules in python can I use?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wifi is a lot easier than bluetooth
2. Yes, batman can do routing in mesh networks. It's used e.g. for [Freifunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freifunk) ad-hoc networks. There are lots of [alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_mesh_network#Protocols).
3. You'll need to get the (a) hardware and (b) WLAN configuration and routing working on the OS level. Python will use the standard OS interfaces to whatever you choose there. You need to come up with a schema for service discovery (or you hardcode the available nodes).
4. Standard networking, and whatever you need to access the OS-level routing layer. It shouldn't be a problem.

Prepare to read up **a lot** of basics if you want to implement this yourself. There's not enough room in a Q&A to go over the basics step-by-step.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I already have a mesh connection via Wi-Fi. Do you have any idea how to create it via Bluetooth? I really need it because it is required.

Comment: IMHO, the Linux bluetooth stack is a major pain in the posterior. Good luck creating a mesh network with it. Sorry, I can't help you. And if you want to communicate both over Bluetooth and WLAN, it's going to be even more fun. (Also, if Bluetooth is a requirement, it doesn't hurt to mention this in the question...)